# what is syntax in ucf file for IOBDELAY for virtex 5?

Tags: syntax, vhdl, fpga, virtex

```
# Sets the attributes to an input differential pin pair (din)
NET <din_p> LOC=<AE7> | IOSTANDARD=<LVDS_25> |IOBDELAY=<NONE/BOTH/IBUF/IFD> | DIFF_TERM=<TRUE>;
NET <din_n> LOC=<AF7> | IOSTANDARD=<LVDS_25> | IOBDELAY=<NONE/BOTH/IBUF/IFD> | DIFF_TERM=<TRUE>;
```

[image]

even when I give IOBDELAY=NONE, the error persists
Could someone tell me where I am going wrong ?
This syntax was taken from Language templates for IBUFDS

Comment: If you don't want to use any delay option, just remove it. No need to specify it in the UCF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yea it had to do with syntax .
    NET "din_p" LOC="AG6" | IOSTANDARD="LVDS_25" | IOBDELAY=NONE | DIFF_TERM=TRUE;

it works this way